# Calling another contract that reverts

Tags: revert-opcode

If i call a function from another contract(using interface), and that function has require statement that reverts... will my function break, or will it continue to execute?

So the question is... will we get to //dosomething or will the transaction revert?

```
contract1 {

    function random1() {
    contract2.random2();
    
    //do something. does this execute or does it revert?

    }
    }
    
    contract2{
    function random2() {
    require(1 > 2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't reach do something. The transaction will revert on :

```
require(1 > 2);
```

And execution will stop.